# Trying to use CWD if not directory is specified in an argument

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a script to rename a bunch of files in a directory. This is what I have so far:

```
cd /$1/
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    cd $PWD
fi
```

So I'm trying to tell the script to run either in the path provided in the argument, or if no argument is provided to use the current working directory.

I've tried a bunch of variations on the if portion:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    cd $CWD
```

And various other things using pwd and cwd but it just isn't working. I keep getting No such file or directory.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm trying to tell the script to run either in the path provided in the argument, or if no argument is provided to use the current working directory.

Since you don't know whether the path provided will be absolute or relative, preceding your target directory with a slash may result in failure.  If you want to use parameter expansion, I'd suggest the following:

```
cd "${1:-.}"
```

This will change to a path provided, relative or absolute, and will not fail on names that include a space.  If `$1` is not provided (and resolves to empty or null), the variable is expanded to a dot, which always refers to the current directory.

That said, I don't have a problem with `if`s.  They help with error detection.  I would think that the following would achieve what you want:

```
if ! cd "${1:-.}"; then
  echo "ERROR: couldn't change to '$1'" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

This is the `cd` from above, but if it fails (for example due to a permission issue or the nonexistence of the path), then the script reports an error (to stderr, hence the `>&2`) and exits.  Otherwise (the `cd` was successful), the script now finds itself in the new location.

Also, I recommend against using `$PWD`, because that's a *variable*, and can be overwritten.  For example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ pwd
/home/ghoti
[ghoti@pc ~]$ PWD=/tmp
[ghoti@pc /tmp]$ echo $PWD
/tmp
[ghoti@pc /tmp]$ pwd
/home/ghoti
[ghoti@pc /tmp]$
```

While the `$PWD` variable gets used for a bunch of things, I would recommend against relying on it unless you set it yourself at the top of your script.

```
PWD=$(pwd)
```

Also, remember to quote your variables.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ mkdir "some dir"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cd "some dir"
[ghoti@pc ~/some dir]$ cd "$PWD"
[ghoti@pc ~/some dir]$ cd $PWD
bash: cd: /home/ghoti/some: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Although dom0's answer behaved as I asked, I am using @ghoti answer because it is more error proof. Thanks for that explanation!

Answer (score 0):

By using variable interpolation you can do this without an if, like this:

```
cd /${1-$PWD}
```

Since `$PWD` is always absolute, if it is used it has two slashes in front. That doesn't matter to `cd`, though.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I believe this fails if the directory in question contains a space or newline, and it will also fail if `$1` is "relative" to the current path, due to the preceding slash.